# How to send form dates for more then one item array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops

I made a cart array and if the user choose more then 1 item to buy to give him the cofirm form, where he will type their data to cofirm the command, but the problem is if i have more then 1 product, the script is show me more then 1 button with sumbit the command, and I want to make only 1 button to sumbit for the command and give all the date from both items to insert in a mysql db

cart.php

```
// Start the For Each loop
        $i = 0; 
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];

            // start select query stmt
            $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, product_name, price, size, details FROM products WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1');
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($idSelect, $product_name, $price, $size, $details);//variabla pe care o vrei inlocuita prin bind_Result in loc de get_Result
            while ($stmt->fetch())    {
               $idSelect;
               $product_name; // faci acelasi lucru fara $row 
               $price;    
               $size;
               $details;    
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
            // stoop select stmt    
            $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
            $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;

            // Create the product array variable
            $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
            // sumbit the command FORM
            //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td><center>' . $pricetotal . ' RON</center></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '</tr>';

            $i++;
            $totalProduse = $item_id -1 + $each_item['quantity'];
            //trimite form to COFIRMA COMANDA
            $cofirmaComanda .='<form  action="cofirma_comanda.php" method="post">
            <input name="prettotal"  type="hidden" value="'. $pricetotal .'">
             <input name="produseID"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">
             <input name="produseNume"  type="hidden" value="'. $product_name .'">
             <input name="size"  type="hidden" value="'. $my_ArraySize .'">
             <input name="cantitate"  type="hidden" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] .'">
             <input name="produse"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">
              <input type="submit" name="CofirmaComanda" value="cofirma_comanda"></form>';

        }
```

the form is `$cofirmaComanda`

and the cofirm command page

```
<?php
$pretTotal = $_POST["prettotal"];
$PRODUSE = $_POST["produseID"];
$produseNume = $_POST["produseNume"];
$size = $_POST["size"];
$cantitate = $_POST["cantitate"];


    if(isset($_POST["sumbitDateClienti"])){
    $nume = $_POST["nume_client"];


    $pretTotalt = $_POST["prettotal"];

    $PRODUSE = $_POST["produseID"];
    $produseNume = $_POST["produseNume"];
    $size = $_POST["size"];
    $cantitate = $_POST["cantitate"];
    $comanda = 'IDprodus: '.$PRODUSE.' / produseNume: '.$produseNume.' / cantitate: '.$cantitate.' / dimensiune: '.$size.' ';

    }

?>
```

Comment: Please reference the code causing the issue, not your whole code expecting others to debug for you. Tell us what part and what issue you're getting.

Comment: Sorry was my mistake i removed the code and i let the code with the problem, sorry I m newbie

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to define your form and submit button outside your `foreach` loop, and use arrays for your hidden variables (simply add `[]` after the name, in the HTML form):

```
$cofirmaComanda = '<form  action="cofirma_comanda.php" method="post">';

foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
    // ...
    $cofirmaComanda .='
        <input name="prettotal[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $pricetotal .'">
        <input name="produseID[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">
        <input name="produseNume[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $product_name .'">
        <input name="size[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $my_ArraySize .'">
        <input name="cantitate[]"  type="hidden" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] .'">
        <input name="produse[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">';
} 

$cofirmaComanda .='<input type="submit" name="CofirmaComanda" value="cofirma_comanda"></form>
```

Then in your `cofirma_comanda.php`, loop to get your POST-ed values, to process each item one by one:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST["prettotal"]); $i++) {
    $pretTotal = $_POST["prettotal"][$i];
    $PRODUSE = $_POST["produseID"][$i];
    $produseNume = $_POST["produseNume"][$i];
    $size = $_POST["size"][$i];
    $cantitate = $_POST["cantitate"][$i];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: on the cofirm_comanda is give me that `Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in E:\wamp\www\MyOnlineStore\cofirma_comanda.php on line 9` and `Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in E:\wamp\www\MyOnlineStore\cofirma_comanda.php on line 10`

Comment: Fixed a typo; was supposed to be `$i<count($_POST["prettotal"])` not `i<count($_POST["prettotal"])`

Comment: I did but know is give me the `produseNume` and `prettotal` for the last items array...